# How to write WHERE not

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a query which will select the column "batchinstructor" from the table "batch" where batchname="$batchname" and the value of "batchid" shouldn't be "$batchid".

I have managed to write the following but it is clearly wrong, would you please kindly correct it for me?

```
SELECT batchinstructor 
FROM batch 
WHERE batchname='$batchname AND batchid is not= '$batchid'
```

Comment: `NOT (A = B)` is equivalent to `A <> B` ... in any case look at [the MySQL operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html). And *please use placeholders* (to, you know, avoid injection attacks in a consistent manner).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT batchinstructor 
FROM batch 
WHERE batchname='$batchname' and  batchid <> '$batchid'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT batchinstructor 
FROM batch 
WHERE batchname='$batchname' and batchid <> '$batchid'
```

or

```
SELECT batchinstructor 
FROM batch 
WHERE batchname='$batchname' and batchid != '$batchid'
```

Note that if batchid is NULL in the table, this won't work. For that, you indeed need to check using IS NOT NULL, because the check 'NULL <> 1' will actually return false, thus returning the records where batchid is NULL. If you got NULL records, you need to change the query to:

```
SELECT batchinstructor 
FROM batch 
WHERE 
  batchname='$batchname' and 
  (batchid is null or batchid != '$batchid')
```

Comment: Please note that `!=` is *not* standard-SQL (but is accepted in MySQL).

Comment: Indeed, but this is a MySQL question. I rather use `<>`, but since some people use `!=` it's convenient to know its meaning. :) Thanks for the addition.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT batchinstructor
  FROM batch
 WHERE batchname='$batchname and  batchid <> '$batchid'
```

This is standard SQL. Some SQL dialects would use

```
SELECT batchinstructor
  FROM batch
 WHERE batchname='$batchname and  batchid != '$batchid'
```

Comment: +1 For pointing out that `!=` is non-standard (although valid in MySQL).